# "Not on FX application" Exception rules

Tags: java, javafx

Everybody knows that only JavaFX thread is should be allowed to modify the GUI in the JavaFX applications, but I get weird behavior around violations of this rule a lot of times, so I have written this simple program:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        VBox root = new VBox();
        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox("");
        checkBox.setSelected(false);
        root.getChildren().add(checkBox);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
        new Thread(()->{
                System.out.println("is FX:"+Platform.isFxApplicationThread());
                try {
                    //line under is 28
                    checkBox.selectedProperty().setValue(!checkBox.isSelected());
                    System.out.println("checkBox selectedProperty is change to:"+checkBox.isSelected()+","+ checkBox.selectedProperty().get());
                }catch (Exception e){
                    System.out.println("checkBox change of selectedProperty is not allow from not FX thread");
                }
                try {
                    //line under is 35
                    checkBox.textProperty().set("test");
                    System.out.println("checkBox textProperty change to: "+checkBox.getText()+","+ checkBox.textProperty().get());
                }catch (Exception e){
                    System.out.println("checkBox change of textProperty is not allow from not FX thread");
                }
            System.out.println("end of thread");
        }).start();

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The output:

```
is FX:false
checkBox selectedProperty is change to:true,true
checkBox textProperty change to: test,test
end of thread
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-3
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:247)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:423)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$3.onProposedChange(Parent.java:493)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:113)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:108)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.updateChildren(LabeledSkinBase.java:271)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.CheckBoxSkin.updateChildren(CheckBoxSkin.java:106)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.lambda$new$11(LabeledSkinBase.java:219)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.LambdaMultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler.lambda$new$1(LambdaMultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.value.WeakChangeListener.changed(WeakChangeListener.java:89)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:181)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(StringPropertyBase.java:104)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.markInvalid(StringPropertyBase.java:111)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:145)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:50)
    at sample.Main.lambda$start$0(Main.java:35)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

as you can see the GUI is effected by the 2 changes:

[image]

but the Exception it only at line 35(`textProperty` change) and not at line 28(`selectedProperty` change)

so my question is this a bug or is this behavior has a reasonable explanation, and if there is such, what it is?

I don't know if it matters but I work with Java 9

Comment: Afaik starting with JavaFX 8 the thread checks were reduced (for performance reasons, I guess). This does not mean it's safe to use those properties from a different thread; there's still no synchronisation of any of the GUI properties and any change could result in the JavaFX application thread seeing a inconsistent state of the node potentially leading to catastrophic results.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is normal. You edit the GUI from a non GUI thread, putting the GUI in an unstable state. The exception happens afterwards when the GUI thread tries to refresh the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

When you change a scene from another thread, then one of the following happens:

- If you are lucky, you get an exception
- Otherwise weird race-conditions might happen.

Not that you are allowed to create a node and modify it from outside the FX application thread, as long as the Node is not attached to a scene.

When you put that node to the scene graph, then you have to use the FX application thread.